# SSRS Empty point show/hide based on execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I have a chart that is pulling data in real time and plotting it with an X axis that spans a full day. I have set empty point to "Average" in order to connect the sections that have no data.

Now my problem is that I want the horizontal line that extends to the right to be cut off at execution time. I've tried to write expressions to alter the color of the empty point line to be "No Color" if after the execution time but to no avail.

This is all written with datasets(no stored procedure) pointing at an Oracle DB

Any Ideas?

[Without Empty point values at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1YGK.png)

[With Empty point values set to Average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWTz0.png)

Comment: I think there is a way to specify you want to fill the empty gaps via a property somewhere on that chart series. I remember doing something similar, let me look.

Comment: I doubt this will help solve your issue but FYI: To set "No Color" you need to use the keyword `Nothing` (no quotes).